# Boundary condition

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions

Consider a viscous fluid filled in a space that spans $[0, H]$ in the $y$-direction but extends to infinity in the $x$-direction with the positive direction pointing to the right. The fluid moves differently according to the following descriptions; specify all the needed boundary conditions you need to solve the 2D problem (in the $x$-$y$ plane); should you need material properties, define them. Neglect gravity.

1. Driven by two solid plates, one moves at $U$ to the right and one moves at $-U/2$ to the left
2. A pumping force that is uniform across H but varies in time as F(t) is applied to drive the fluid motion between two stationary plates. Neglect the entrance effect for now.
3. The base plate remains stationary while the top surface is subject to an air stream blowing to the right at U. Neglect gravity and assume that the free surface remains flat.
4. The base plate remains stationary but now a solid plate of length L is placed motionless on the top surface; define x=0 at the center of the plate. Now the plate pushes downward at a constant velocity V at time t=0 we want to solve the induced flow motion in time up to H/V.  Write down all the needed BCs